# Find a closed formula for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, closed-form, binomial-theorem

Find a closed formula for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}$

I am trying to use the derivative of generalized binomial theorem, $\frac{d}{dx}[(x+1)^r=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{r}{n}x^n] =r(x+1)^{r-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \binom{r}{n}nx^{n-1}$

However, I am not sure how to "get rid" of the binomial term.

Comment: Binomial theorem uses summation to a finite number not infinity $\infty$- See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem. Also for such infinite sum to converge you need to put a condition on $x$, otherwise the series will not converge.

Comment: the generalized binomial theorem, for any value including non integer values of r, is an infinite sum, like a Taylor series

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that for $|x|<1$, we have $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

Taking derivatives of both sides

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

On the LHS, when $n=0$, the term vanishes.  Thus

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

Comment: would this be true without the qualification that $|x|<1$ ?

Comment: @mentorship no. the series only holds for those restricted x values.

Comment: @mentorship: No, then the sum diverges

Comment: I am wondering then if that is the closed form for this was not specified.

Comment: Consider as an example, when $x=2$...1+2+4+8+16+32+64+...=-1/2?