# Geometric summation question

Tags: derivatives, summation, induction

Differentiate both sides of the geometric sum with respect to $r$.$$\sum_{i=0}^n r^i = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$
Use the result to show that  $$\sum_{i=1}^n ir^i < \frac{r}{(1-r)^2} \text{ for all } n\ge1 .$$

Comment: Uh...and what have you tried...?  For starters, what did you get after differentiation?

Comment: If you know that $(1)$ $\dfrac d {dr} r^i = ir^{i-1}$ and $(2)$ the quotient rule and $(3)$ the derivative of the sum of several terms is the sum of their derivatives, then you've got it.

Comment: Maybe of interest http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652794/find-a-closed-formula-for-sum-n-1-infty-nxn-1